# MSMQ to WCF - automatic notification

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have an application that places messages on MSMQ, than I have a WCF service that I want to automatically read these messages from MSMQ.
I do not want to trigger my WCF service but I want it to be notified whenever a message is pushed on MSMQ. I have found some stuff related to WAS and netMSMQBinding, but the details seems a little unclear about automatic notifications from MSMQ to WCF.
Any help/direction in this regard? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is it that you're trying to achieve?

There is really no such thing as "be notified when a message is pushed on MSMQ". MSMQ uses a pull model to retrieve messages from a queue, so there always needs to exist some kind of "listener" that reads messages from the queue and processes them.

In this case, this "listener" is provided by the WCF NetMsmq or MsmqIntegration bindings automatically, so the programming model for a WCF service that is exposed over MSMQ is just like that of a regular one-way service.

As you state, you can either host that WCF service using your own custom host (such as a Windows service), or, in many cases, the preferred method will be to host that service in IIS 7.X/8.X through WAS.

The following sample shows how to host an MSMQ service in WAS: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246(v=vs.110).aspx

Notice that you do need some specific configuration in IIS to be able to host non-HTTP services, which includes enabling the "Non-HTTP Service Activation" feature. The following articles will be useful to get this done:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/13/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/14/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-3.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/05/17/building-a-pub-sub-message-bus-with-wcf-and-msmq.aspx